# Script to detect user session over RDP or direct (native) from the box

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rdp, xrdp

I want to write a script to **detect if the current gnome session** is from a **RDP connection** via [xRDP server](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xrdp/) or its a **native launched gnome session**.

In this case, I would like the native session(s) to start an application.

But I'm unsure where to get started. Is there any environment variable I could check for?

Thanks.

Comment: check the DISPLAY environment variable, it might be different for a virtual session vs one at the X Server.